# Jenkins fails running MSBuild command

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

This is my Jenkinsfile, and I have MSBuild plugin installed in Jenkins. The msbuild command below is correct as I can run it from the command line, yet Jenkins keeps failing on it. If I remove the parameter it's complaining about then it fails on next one, etc...

Jenkinsfile (saved in git repository):

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        docker 'node:7.7.3'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                bat echo 'Checking node.js version..'
                bat echo 'node -v'
                bat echo 'Restore nugets..'
                bat 'nuget restore mySolution.sln'
                bat echo 'Building..'
                bat "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\msbuild.exe" mySolution.sln /noautorsp /ds /nologo /t:clean,rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /v:m /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /clp:Summary;ErrorsOnly;WarningsOnly /p:ProductVersion=1.0.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                bat echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                bat echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            bat echo 'Pipeline Succeeded'
        }
        failure {
            bat echo 'Pipeline Failed'
        }
        unstable {
            bat echo 'Pipeline run marked unstable'
        }       
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 14: expecting '}', found '/' @ line 14, column 84.
   \msbuild.exe" mySolution.sln /noautorsp
                                 ^
```

Comment: It is possible you need to escape the slashes. Can you try putting single quotes around the complete command in line 14? Like this: bat 'command'

Comment: Same exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the entire `bat` argument needs to be in quotes, so:

```
bat "'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\msbuild.exe' mySolution.sln /noautorsp /ds /nologo /t:clean,rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /v:m /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /clp:Summary;ErrorsOnly;WarningsOnly /p:ProductVersion=1.0.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

Otherwise, it's treating `mySolution.sln` as a Groovy keyword, then `/noautorsp`, etc. You could also avoid the full path to MSBuild.exe here by defining it as a tool in Jenkins (via the [MSBuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin)), then doing what I describe at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45592810/466874.